# Microsoft Excel speech using VBA - speak more than one item?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using the following code to read out the contents of a cell in Microsoft

Excel.

```
Sub Warning()
With Range("A1")
    .Speak
     End With

End Sub
```

I would like to now read out the contents of several cells as part of a

sentence.

FOR EXAMPLE

If A1 contains a name and B1 contains the value of either 'Morning',

'afternoon' or 'evening' as text, then I would like the PC to speak the

following then the sub Warning is called

"Good morning John Doe, how are you today?"

I've tried adding in `.value("Good morning")` before reading the John Doe bit,

but I can't get it to read more than one thing at a time.

Can anyone help?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Call the `Speech` object directly instead of via `Range`:

```
Application.Speech.Speak "Good " & Range("B1").Value & " " & Range("A1").Value & ", How are you today?"
```

Answer (score 1):

This will read the text in column **A:**

```
Sub Recite()
    L = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For n = 1 To L
        Cells(n, 1).Speak
    Next n
End Sub
```